# Is there any way to get the default gateway on UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

Normally I can get the default gateway with the API NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces.

But in UWP, that method is not implemented.

Is there any alternative way to get it?

Comment: I just got some information from https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/9675

Answer (score 0):

`NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces` is supported on .NET Standard 2.0.

This means you can use the API and you need to set the minimum version of the project to 16299 (1709).

Best regards.